# Enable IP(v4) forwarding on Linux Mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, ipv4

How do I enable IP forwarding on Linux Mint? When typing the following commands in the terminal as superuser I got the following output:

```
DALEK zermacr0yd # sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
DALEK zermacr0yd # /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
DALEK zermacr0yd #
```

Comment: Just for info, the second command is wrong: you should `cat` the file: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Answer (score 1):

This will either be because apparmor or SELinux is running.

If you are using apparmor you can temporarily disable it (as root) with

```
invoke-rc.d apparmor stop
```

If you are using selinux you should be able to dsiable it temporarily (as root) with

```
setenforce 0
```